# Expansions of Hermite functions

Tags: reference-request, special-functions, approximation, approximation-theory

I am wondering if someone knows good references. I am looking for expansions of Hermite functions, which gives connections between rates of decay and smoothness of coefficients.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I've found [*Special Functions: An Intro. to the Classical Functions of Mathematical Physics* by Nico Temme](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471113131) very helpful.

Comment: I don't think there's anything in that book about Hermite expansions.